# Access fields of a struct dynamically

Tags: c, struct

I have defined these 2 structs:

```
#define MAP_SIZE 5

typedef struct battle_cell {
  int status_a;
  int status_b;

  int ship_a;
  int ship_b;
} battle_cell;

struct battlemap {
  battle_cell cell[MAP_SIZE][MAP_SIZE];
  int progress_a;
  int progress_b;
};
```

After the initalization of the map and all the other variables with zeros:

```
for (i = 0; i < MAP_SIZE; i++) {
  for (j = 0; j < MAP_SIZE; j++) {
    map->cell[i][j].status_a = 0;
    map->cell[i][j].status_b = 0;
    map->cell[i][j].ship_a = 0;
    map->cell[i][j].ship_b = 0;
  }
}

map->progress_a = 0;
map->progress_b = 0;
```

There is a point that I have to check the ship_a and ship_b values that live in each cell, something like that (the logic is a bit more complex than this iteration):

```
for (i = posXB; i < posXB + SHIP_SIZE; i++) {
  map->cell[posYB][i].ship_b = 1;
}
```

I need to do exactly the same for the ship_a variable. So, I have to duplicate quite a big chunk of code because I am not able to find a way to get the field within the struct dynamically. For example, I could define a function:

```
void cell_iteration (battlemap *map, int pos, int pos_y, int ship_size, /* field_parameter/pointer */) {
  int i;
  for (i = pos; i < pos + ship_size; i++) {
    map->cell[pos_y][i].ship_b = 1; // use the field_parameter/pointer instead of ship_b
  }
}
```

Is there an elegant way to do something like that?

***UPDATE***

Just a clarification. The structs can definitely be simplified, but this is not my question. I 've just tried to create an example :)

Comment: You can probably simplify the data structure. Maybe you could define a ship structure that contains the position(s) of a ship, rather than put so much inside the battle_cell struct.

Comment: @Stuart definitely the structs can be simplified and this is what the guy below answered. I 've tried to simulate a complicated case just to give an example. I think that I have to edit the question to clarify this :)

Comment: I'm probably not understanding your question because I don't see how creating an array[2] of ships inside battle_cell helps you. I'm thinking that instead of a field parameter pointer you just need a parameter that indicates which ship you want to access and then have the code access either or maybe both ships.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "access dynamically the properties of the struct".

Comment: @Stuart Defining an array[2], you can make an assumption that the 0 position will be ship_a and position 1 will be ship_b. Then you can pass simple integer 0 and 1 and will be able to access the fields (at least this is what I understood). I am not 100% sure if I understood your suggestion, though. Is it possible to create a very small snippet and post it as an answer?

Comment: @Stuart It means that I have a function and has two arguments. One is a struct and the other one can be an array of chars (string). The function using the string will be able to return a property of the struct. For example, if  the string is "ship_a" and this is part of the struct then the function will return the struct->ship_a;

Comment: Ah! I understand, you mean define an array and pass an index into the array. This is probably simpler that what I was thinking of.

Comment: No, C doesn't support accessing struct members like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead if `ship_a` and `ship_b` int the first struct, you can declare `int ship[2]` an array of 2 `int`.

Comment: This is a solution that can work, but I would really like to know if there is a way to access dynamically the properties of the struct.

Comment: I thought the compiler is smart enough to do this on his own.